# Trouble with Blender's snapping tools and origin orientation

Tags: modeling

[image]

I've spent a lot of time in Maya. I really love Blender so far! But its snapping tools are a pain in the butt.

As a project to learn animation, I made a cylinder with cubes extracted and separated from it. I want the cubes to all recede into the holes on the cylinder until all faces line up perfectly.

In Maya this is super easy. Hold the D and V key, snap the origin to a vertex, then hold the V key to snap the object's origin to another vertex. It takes 2 seconds. In Maya I can also set the orientation of the origin to any selected face's normal direction.

I would LOVE LOVE LOVE an easier way to deal with object origins and snapping in Blender!!! And is there a way to set origin orientation of a whole object to a selected face's normal direction?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Allen

Comment: you mean a video of how Maya does it? I would have to reinstall Maya but I suppose it would be worth it.

Comment: In Maya there's no cursor. You hold down the 'D' key and you can put the origin of an object anywhere.   If you also hold down 'V', it will snap to any vertex. Then you have an object with an origin on a vertex.       It's so fast its not even a thought.

Comment: if I select an object in Maya, and select any of its faces, I can choose "set orientation to facenormal'.  Then The origin axis will shoot in the direction of the face direction for the whole object.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pElYhd4J_vU

Comment: That was the shortest most informative video I could find. This method of placing origins is so fast (comparatively). Maya's snapping tools put Blender to shame. There's got to be some sort of plugin or something so that I don't have to place the cursor every single time I move an object's origin.

Comment: setting an object's origin to a face's direction is also something I don't think Blender has (I can't find it if it does).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23608/discussion-between-zeffii-and-allen).